# Eigenvalues are roots of cyclotomic polynomial

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, primitive-roots, cyclotomic-polynomials

I am reading Lyndon and Shupp's 'combinatorial group theory'. At page 25 it is stated that

> if $g$ is an element of finite order $n$ in $\mathbb{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$, its eigenvalues must be roots of the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$,$\ldots$

I can see why the eigenvalues are $n$th roots of unity, but I do not see why they should be primitive roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false. Take$$g=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$Then $g$ has order $2$, but only one of its eigenvalues is a root of $\Phi_2$.

Comment: The book goes on in saying that therefore $\Phi_n(x)$ should divide the characteristic polynomial, which has degree $2$ at most. Would you know how to fix the statement (it is used to prove that the only elements of finite order can have order $1,2,3,4$ or $6$).

Comment: @Student I don't have time for this right now. My suggestion is that you post it as another question, with a link to this question.